# How to shut down a computer (host)

Tags: deno

I know it sounds weird, but I have a case where Deno would need to shutdown its own host (and kill its own process therefore). Is this possible?

I am specifically needing this for linux (lubuntu), if that's relevant. I guess this requires sudo rights, which sucks but would be an option.

For those interested in details: I'm coding a minecraft server software and if the server has no player for 30 minutes, it will shut itself down to save some power. A raspberry PI that runs 24/7 anyways, has a wake on lan feature, so that it can boot again. After boot, the server manager software would automatically start as a linux service.

Comment: You can use Deno’s subprocess API to do this (note that the subprocess API [is changing](https://deno.com/blog/v1.21#new-unstable-api-for-subprocesses)), and shutting down the OS would use the shell as the base process (e.g. `sh`). Are you running Deno on a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @jsejcksn No I run it on a normal computer (home server). :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [create a subprocess](https://deno.land/manual@v1.25.1/examples/subprocess) to do this:

```
await Deno.run({ cmd: ["shutdown", "-h", "now"] }).status();
```

> ### Concepts
>
> - Deno is capable of spawning a subprocess via [Deno.run](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/Deno.run).
> - `--allow-run` permission is required to spawn a subprocess.
> - Spawned subprocesses do not run in a security sandbox.
> - Communicate with the subprocess via the [stdin](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/Deno.stdin), [stdout](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/Deno.stdout) and [stderr](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/Deno.stderr) streams.
> - Use a specific shell by providing its path/name and its string input switch, e.g. `Deno.run({cmd: ["bash", "-c", "ls -la"]});`

---

See also [command line - Shutdown from terminal without entering password? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/168879/shutdown-from-terminal-without-entering-password) for ideas on how to avoid needing `sudo` to call `shutdown` or alternative commands that you can invoke from Deno instead.

Comment: Thanks a million! I wrote another answer on how I made it work, as I struggled with the links you provided for shutting down a computer without a password prompt. Lots of information that did not work for me. But I will keep your answer accepted of course, as you deserve all the credit for it and provided all the core info needed, thanks a lot! https://stackoverflow.com/a/73654726/2311557

Answer (score 1):

To extend on what [@mfulton2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3255152/mfulton26) wrote, here is how I made it work, so that I did not need to start the program with sudo rights, but still was able to shut down the computer without the use of `sudo` outside or within the app.

1. Open or create the following file: `sudo nano /etc/sudoer`
2. Add the line `username ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown`
3. Add this line `%admin  ALL = NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown`
4. In your deno script, write `Deno.run({ cmd: ["shutdown", "-h", "now"]}).status();`
5. Execute script!

Keep in mind that any experienced linux user would potentially tell you that this is very dangerous (it probably is) and that it might not be the very best way. But IMHO, the damage this can cause is minor enough, as it only affects the `shutdown` command.